# How to create virtual Environment for users on server

Tags: python, linux, apache, deployment

I have a web application where users can register them self and then save Java and C++ programs in their account.
Programs are saved in a tmp directory like,
/tmp
  -user1
   --program1
   --program2
  -user2
   --program1
   --program2

So all the users folders are in same "tmp" directory.
I want to know how can I proved security by not allowing a user to access files of other users. A user will be executing a java or c++ program in his folder which can be used to read files on the server. How to prevent this?
I am new to this thing I don't know how to go about this.

The server is Linux server and project is in python using Django.

Thank in advance

Comment: create seperate tmp dir for each user and update TMPDIR environment variable.

Comment: I don't think that will solve the problem completely related to security especially during execution of a Java or C++ program.
A user can simple right a program to scan files outside the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that separates what each process sees of the systems.  If you were using FreeBSD, their [Jails](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/jails.html) system would be your perfect solution.

As Linux alternative you could consider [Linux vserver](http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org) instances, or biting the bullet and setting up a heaver virtualization environment like Xen.

Both of these are virtualization solutions that basically allow you to run an instance of a virtual server that uses a particular directory as its root.  Processes run in the same kernel as your host system, but are isolated from the rest of the system.  Think of them like "chroot" with additional isolation of network stack and process tree.  The work involved in setting up and tearing down new jails or vservers can be very fast.

If you can, I suggest you switch to FreeBSD.  Jails enjoy a much more vibrant development and support community than the (now declining) vserver solution in Linux.